# Raw Access Logs File Too Big to Open

Tags: cpanel, filesize, access-log

My raw access logs file is 420 MB and when I try to open, the program says it is too big and can't open it. I tried opening it with notepad, notepad++ and Excel, and none of them could open it. And the file is only for 3 days worth of logs. How can I view the file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading whole file at a same time, I will suggest you some tool to split text file. For Windows file splitter called **HJSplit**, And for the linux you can use **split** command for this.